# ASP.net details view column not being inserted into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to insert items into a database using Details View. I'm using a dropdownList to insert the CategoryID column because it is a foreign key and I don't want the user to be able to insert any number they want. The dropdownlist is getting it's values from the primary key in the Categories table. For some reason, the other rows are being inserted but the categoryID has a null value in the database. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. Here's some of the code from the design page.

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDetailsViewDDl" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id] FROM [Categories]" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Categories] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>




</div>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" OnItemDeleting="DetailsView1_ItemDeleting" Width="250px">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>      
                    <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="sqlDetailsViewDDl" DataTextField="Id" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>                                            
                        <asp:Label ID="CategoryLabel" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: In case you're unaware, defining your database access directly in your view is an absolute horrible idea. If you want to do it right you should be creating a repository for this so that the front end of your application has no knowledge of where the data comes from or details such as connection strings, it simply exposes methods such as `GetCategories`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was missing this in the dropdownList

```
 SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>'
```